# In Java, how can I avoid an HTTP 404 getting a file:// URL with special characters in it?

Tags: java, url, file, http-status-code-404

First I'll provide a tiny code snippet here:

```
String path = "".equals(url.getPath()) ? "/" : url.getPath();
java.io.File f = new java.io.File(path);

if (!f.exists()) {
    this.code = 404;  // http Not Found
    return;
}
```

Here, the URL's type is `java.net.URL`,and its value has this format:

```
file:///directory1/directory2.../filename
```

the above code works 90% of the time when it's processing general URLs, But it fails when the file name has special characters in it. For example:

```
/tmp/Marissafolli/Receptionist/Administrative Assistant/Marissa's Resume.txt.txt
```

URLs like this will report a "404" code, even if they exist.  The following version will work for those special cases:

```
java.io.File f = new java.io.File(url.toURI());
```

But `url.toURI()` is only in j2SE 1.5.0. So I need to use the first version. How can I make it work?

Comment: Where are the original url's coming from?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's the fact that it's not a valid URL.

You obviously need to [escape](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html) those blanks into %20, for starters.  I don't know what you do with the apostrophe.  [This blog](http://blog.steeleprice.net/archive/2004/07/13/365.aspx) suggests that it should become a %27.  Try it and see.

Or just try [java.net.URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to see what it gives you.

Comment: I don't believe you can use URLEncoder, as it will encode *everything* including the "://" characters.  Java itself does not have a class to do the necessary encoding.

Comment: You might be right, Eddie.  I didn't try it myself.  I was just rooting around for something in the API that might help.  Perhaps that wasn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct a URI first and then call the toURL() method. More info [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html).

[UPDATE] Or even better, why not use the URI directly in the constructor of the File, since the URI class takes care of the encoding for you.